# How do I update a Bokeh server when data becomes available via callbacks?

Tags: python, callback, bokeh

I'm very new to event loops / callbacks in general. I'm using this server approach so I can run it in Pycharm easily, based on another post.

I want to graph the results of iterative algorithms for optimizing the path of gcode for physical pen plotters (TS problem).

So I need the bokeh plot to update once a cycle of the algorithm completes. Here is a script based on other posts that updates the data whenever the slider callback is triggered. As a stand-in for real data it generates random values.

```py
import numpy as np
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

io_loop = IOLoop.current()


def getData():
    l = 50
    x = np.random.rand(1, l)
    y = np.random.rand(1, l)
    return (dict(x=x, y=y))


def modify_doc(doc):
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=getData())

    plot = figure()
    plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)

    slider = Slider(start=1, end=10, value=1, step=0.1)

    def callback(attr, old, new):
        source.data = getData()

    slider.on_change('value', callback)

    doc.add_root(column(slider, plot))


bokeh_app = Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))

server = Server({'/': bokeh_app}, io_loop=io_loop)
server.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Opening Bokeh application on http://localhost:5006/')
    io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    io_loop.start()
```

However I can't work out where I would put a loop / callback to update the plot once per loop, rather than based on input from the slider. It should be something like

```
best-solution = []

for i in range(100):
    run slow algorithm on best-solution
    find best-result
    update plot with best-result
    best-solution = best-result
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To start any arbitrary code you could use a button with the code to run in the button callback.

```
def modify_doc(doc):
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=getData())

    def do_stuff():

        for i in range(100):

            ... do_stuff with the data ...

            source.data = data

    button = Button(label='do stuff')
    button.on_click(do_stuff)    

    plot = figure()
    plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)

    doc.add_root(column(button, plot))
```